# Lost terminal PATH, cant use any commands or access directories

Tags: bash, path, terminal

I was trying to setting up Sublime text 2 for the terminal using [this](https://gist.github.com/artero/1236170).  It didn't work, and now the terminal cant access any directories or use simple commands like ls or cd.

**Examples**

```
$ ls
-bash: ls: No such file or directory

$ python
-bash: python: No such file or directory
```

I think my PATH is screwed up but i dont know how to fix it.  Thanks in advance

Also if I echo $PATH, it is blank.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general tech support.

Comment: create a folder called e.g. `dotfiles` and copy all your, well, dotfiles there like .bashrc, .vimrc, .muttrc etc. Put them under revision control using git/mercury and store them on github/bitbucket. In that way this error solves easily, you also get the benefit of having acces to your configfiles from *any* computer.

Answer (score 4):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

This is a reasonable default. Run that at your terminal to fix that shell's path. Note that it won't affect other (future) shells.

Comment: Thanks i used this to get it working again then edited the ~/.bash_profile

Comment: next time create a file and use 'source' to make changes to env before changing your .bash_profile or create a backup before you do

Answer (score 2):

You can run commands by typing their full path, e.g. `/bin/ls`. Use an editor this way to fix whichever startup file you messed up.